# Using the #href convention in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```js
document.getElementById('otherButton').addEventListener('click', function () {

document.getElementById("step-4").style.display = 'block'

});
```

```html
<link href="https://www.mapbox.com/base/latest/base.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class='col12 pad4 contain fill-navy dark clip'>
  <div class='center quiet'>Map Canvas</div>
  <div class='pin-right pad2'>
    <a href='#step-4' class='button'>Trigger</a>
  </div>
  <div id='step-4' class='col4 pad2 fill-darken1 pin-left offcanvas-left animate'>
    <a href='#' class='fill-darken2 pad1 icon close'></a>
  </div>
</div>
<div id='otherButton' class='button'>otherButton</div>
```

I am using [this example](https://www.mapbox.com/base/tutorials/single-page-app/) (shown above) as a guide for html and css on my webpage.  In the example, we see that clicking on the button whose `href=#step4` will display the div with id `step-4`

In javascript, if I want to open this exact same div on click, how would I do this ?  For your reference, the css page is [here](http://mapbox.com/base/latest/base.css)

```
document.getElementById('otherButton').addEventListener('click', function () {

document.getElementById("step-4").style.display = 'block'

});
```

doesn't work.  What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: do you want to scroll until the `step-4` or is it not visible at the start?

Comment: You do not have an element with id `otherButton`

Comment: My guess is one of those classes is styled to make the div not visible (`offcanvas-left`, for instance).

Comment: `otherButton` exists in the html, it's just an example

Comment: @T.J.Crowder how would one make it visible in js?

Comment: Well, if it's the class that's making it not visible, then logically, what would make it visible?

Comment: @TJ I think it's not the class, you can see in the example that by clicking on the Trigger button, it works.  I am interested in how to set `step-4` to visible in pure javascript.  Is this possible?

Comment: I did say "guess." :-) In any case, the full content of your question must be **in** your question, not just linked. Links rot, making the question and its answers useless to people in the future, and people shouldn't have to go off-site to help you. Put a [mcve] **in** the question, ideally using Stack Snippets (the `<>` toolbar button) to make it runnable ([here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-do-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do-tha)). More: [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder  thanks, I have done so above

Comment: Please say what we're supposed to do/see when running the snippet. All i get is a Trigger button which, when I click it, gives me an [X] button. Is that what I meant to see? Also: Again: The content **must be in the question**. Those styles are not in the question, they're still just linked.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I have expanded the snippet - not sure how to include those styles in the question as the css page is extremely long.  https://www.mapbox.com/base/latest/base.css

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, *what we are supposed to do* seems to trigger the `:target` pseudo-class programmatically.

Comment: Actually @T.J.Crowder is right the question is vague, but thats because the instructions from the website is pretty vague too. In css there are several ways to make a div 'invisible'. You can make its display:none; This is what you assumed in your question but this isn't right, the display is alway block. The creators of the site (i think) actually just translated the block out of the containing div and have overflow set to hidde. Clicking the trigger translates the div into view. If you want to know how to do this, reform your question.

Comment: *"not sure how to include those styles in the question as the css page is extremely long"* That's where [mcve] comes in.

Comment: You will need to have style like attribute in your html tag if you wanna to access it. Thats the problem here !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The CSS trick the example uses is that it looks at the [`:target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:target) pseudo-class.
When you click on the anchor, the fragment-identifier is set as the hash of your page, and your `step-4` element is then the one which matches this selector, activating the `transform: translateX(0)` rule, which will make the element visible.

So what you want is actually to trigger the `:target` pseudo-class programmatically.

And this can be achieved by manipulating the `location.hash` property.

```js
btn.onclick = e => {
  location.hash = "myDiv";
}
```

```css
div:target{
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="myDiv">Hello</div>
<button id="btn">click me</button>
```

Or with your example:

```js
document.getElementById('otherButton').addEventListener('click', function () {

location.hash = 'step-4';

});
```

```html
<link href="https://www.mapbox.com/base/latest/base.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class='col12 pad4 contain fill-navy dark clip'>
  <div class='center quiet'>Map Canvas</div>
  <div class='pin-right pad2'>
    <a href='#step-4' class='button'>Trigger</a>
  </div>
  <div id='step-4' class='col4 pad2 fill-darken1 pin-left offcanvas-left animate'>
    <a href='#' class='fill-darken2 pad1 icon close'></a>
  </div>
</div>
<div id='otherButton' class='button'>otherButton</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not that the display is none, or that visibility is set to hidden. The problem is that the div has a class called 'offcanvas-left' that translates it off the canvas (and the canvas has overflow set to hidden). If you want to signal the div coming into view you can translate it right or simply remove the class 'offcanvas-left'.

```js
document.getElementById('otherButton').addEventListener('click', function () {

document.getElementById("step-4").classList.remove('offcanvas-left');

});
```

```html
<link href="https://www.mapbox.com/base/latest/base.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class='col12 pad4 contain fill-navy dark clip'>
  <div class='center quiet'>Map Canvas</div>
  <div class='pin-right pad2'>
    <a href='#step-4' class='button'>Trigger</a>
  </div>
  <div id='step-4' class='col4 pad2 fill-darken1 pin-left offcanvas-left animate'>
    <a href='#' class='fill-darken2 pad1 icon close'></a>
  </div>
</div>
<div id='otherButton' class='button'>otherButton</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to have style like attribute in your html tag if you wanna to access it.

Here is example :

```js
document.getElementById('otherButton').addEventListener('click', function () {
alert(document.getElementById("step-4").style.display)
document.getElementById("step-4").style.display = 'none';

} , false);
```

```html
<link href="https://www.mapbox.com/base/latest/base.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class='col12 pad4 contain fill-navy dark clip'>
  <div class='center quiet'>Map Canvas</div>
  <div class='pin-right pad2'>
    <a href='#step-4' class='button'>Trigger</a>
  </div>
  <div id='step-4' class='col4 pad2 fill-darken1 pin-left offcanvas-left animate' style="display:block;">
    <a href='#' class='fill-darken2 pad1 icon close'></a>
  </div>
</div>
<div id='otherButton' class='button'>otherButton</div>
```